Showing that 3 points in a triangle are collinear
In a triangle ABC, the 2 altitudes [AD] and [BE] intersect with each other at point M. Let F,G and H be the respective mid-points of the line segments [AB],[DE] and [MC]. The problem is to show that points F,G and H are collinear.
I'm wondering if we can do this using coordinate geometry by finding the equation of the line (FG), and then plug in the coordinates of point H and realize that they verify its equation, but that doesn't seem to lead to any progress, so any hint or help are much appreciated. And here's what the shape looks like: https://www.geogebra.org/m/c7aehgzv

Welcome to MSE. If you are able to add a diagram that would really help. Also, giving some context is a good idea because "help me with my homework" type questions tend to get ignored here.

I just added a diagram, hope it would help

You may find it easier to work with vectors than coordinate geometry. The perpendicular lines you need for the altitudes would be a bit simpler to write.

This works not only when AD and BE are altitudes (in fact, they can be any cevians; see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%E2%80%93Gauss_line)

A non-coordinate approach: In your notation, $FH$ is a diameter of the 9-point circle of $\triangle{ABC}$, and such diameters always bisect the opposing side of the orthic triangle (here $DE$), hence $F,G,H$ are collinear.
To elaborate: red linear are altitudes, green points are midpoints, M is the orthocenter where the altitudes intersect, and red points are midway between the vertices and the orthocenter. These 9 points define the 9-point circle. In the 9-point circle, diameters like $HF$, formed of a midpoint and the midpoint of the orthocenter-vertex segment, are always perpendicular to a side of the orthic triangle, here $ED$, and diameters perpendicular to chords bisect them, hence the point they meet is $G$.


Set up a coordinate system with $BC$ along the $x$-axis, and $D$ at the origin, so that:
$$A = (0, a)$$
$$B = (b, 0)$$
$$C = (c, 0)$$
$$D = (0, 0)$$
Point $E$ is on line $AC$, which has the equation $y = \frac{-a}{c}x + a$.  In order to have $BE \perp AC$, the slope of $BE$ must be $\frac{c}{a}$.  Since $BE$ passes through $B = (b, 0)$, its equation is $y = \frac{c}{a}(x - b)$.  Solving for the intersection of $AC$ and $BE$, we get
$$E = (\frac{a^2c + bc^2}{a^2 + c^2}, \frac{ac^2 - abc}{a^2 + c^2})$$
Point $M$ is the intersection of $AD$ ($x = 0$) and $BE$ ($y = \frac{c}{a}(x - b)$), so:
$$M = (0, -\frac{bc}{a})$$
The midpoint of a line segment is simply the arithmetic mean of its endpoints, so:
$$F = \frac{A + B}{2} = (\frac{b}{2}, \frac{a}{2})$$
$$G = \frac{D + E}{2} = (\frac{c(a^2 + bc)}{2(a^2 + c^2)}, \frac{ac(c - b)}{2(a^2 + c^2)})$$
$$H = \frac{M + C}{2} = (\frac{c}{2}, -\frac{bc}{2a})$$
The equation of line $FH$ works out to:
$$y = \frac{a^2 + bc}{a(b - c)}x + \frac{c(a^2 + b^2)}{2a(c - b)}$$
Plugging in $x = \frac{c(a^2 + bc)}{2(a^2 + c^2)}$ from point $G$ gives:
$$y = \frac{a^2 + bc}{a(b - c)} \cdot \frac{c(a^2 + bc)}{2(a^2 + c^2)} + \frac{c(a^2 + b^2)}{2a(c - b)}$$
$$= \frac{c(a^2 + bc)^2}{2a(b - c)(a^2 + c^2)} + \frac{c(a^2 + b^2)}{2a(c - b)}$$
$$= \frac{c(a^2 + bc)^2 - c(a^2 + b^2)(a^2 + c^2) }{2a(b - c)(a^2 + c^2)}$$
$$= \frac{c(a^4 + 2a^2bc + b^2c^2) - c(a^4 + a^2c^2 + a^2b^2 + b^2c^2) }{2a(b - c)(a^2 + c^2)}$$
$$= \frac{2a^2bc^2 - a^2c^3 - a^2b^2c}{2a(b - c)(a^2 + c^2)}$$
$$= \frac{ac(2bc - b^2 - c^2)}{2(b - c)(a^2 + c^2)}$$
$$= \frac{-ac(b - c)^2}{2(b - c)(a^2 + c^2)}$$
$$= \frac{ac(c - b)}{2(a^2 + c^2)}$$
Which is the $y$ coordinate of $G$.
Therefore, $G$ is on line $FH$.  IOW, points $F$, $G$, and $H$ are collinear, QED.
